# For each unique value in pandas column, sort other columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe as follows.

```
id      name      order
104337  CCC       7.0
104337  BBB       8.0
104337  AAA       9.0
104341  EE        1.0
104341  DD        2.0
```

I would like to group it by `id` with **reversing** the `order` for each `id` as follows.

```
id      name.     order
104337  AAA        9.0
104337  BBB        8.0
104337  CCC        7.0                  
104341  DD         2.0
104341  EE         1.0
```

I have tried `df.groupby('id').apply(f)` but I am confused how to create `f` function for my desired output.

Comment: when you sort, you can just choose the reverse order! https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html

Comment: I want to sort it for each id separately. how do you think I can do it for each id group?

Answer (score 2):

Let's try

```py
out = (df.groupby('id', as_index=False)
       .apply(lambda g: g.sort_values('order', ascending=False))
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(out)

       id name  order
0  104337  AAA    9.0
1  104337  BBB    8.0
2  104337  CCC    7.0
3  104341   DD    2.0
4  104341   EE    1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first do `groupby.apply` then do `sort_values` too.

```
df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x:x).sort_values('order', ascending=False)

       id name  order
2  104337  AAA    9.0
1  104337  BBB    8.0
0  104337  CCC    7.0
4  104341   DD    2.0
3  104341   EE    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it I think using the following code.

```
df.sort_values(['order'],ascending=False).groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x['name'])
```

Comment: You can try this too `df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x:x.sort_values('order', ascending=False))`